# I cannot insert my custom category in wp_term_relationships table when i save new post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I create website where unregistered users can save different ad from fronted. Now it just test study where i try insert data to wp_posts and wp_term_relationships tables. 
I hard wrote *'post_category' => array(3)* just for test.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) &&  wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_nonce_field'], 'name_of_my_action'  )){
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter a title';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the content';
}
$post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $description,
    'post_status'   => 'pending',
    'post_type' => 'category',
    'post_category' => array(3),
);
wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
wp_redirect( home_url() );
exit;
}
```

html form :

```
<form  name="new_post" method="post" action="">
        <p><label class="form__title" for="title"></label><br />
            <input class="form__title-input" type="text"  size="20" name="title" />
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="category">
                <?php foreach ($terms as $el) :?>
                    <?php echo "<option>". $el->name. "</option>" ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($customTags as $el) :?>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <?php echo '<input class="form-check-input" name"check_list" type="checkbox" id="'.$el->term_id. '" value="ZAGlushKa">'?>
    <?php echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">'.$el->name.'</label>'?>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <p><label class="form__title" for="description">About You</label><br />
            <textarea class="form__content-area"  name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p><label class="form__title"></label><br />
            <input class="form__title-input" type="text" value=""  size="16" name="post_tags"/>
        </p>
        <p><input class="form__submit" type="submit" value="Publish" name="submit" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="professionals" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'name_of_my_action', 'name_of_nonce_field' );?>
    </form>
```

**I just want save post in wp_posts table  with relationships in wp_term_relationships table.**

Comment: Now my script insert data only to wp_posts table.

Comment: Your post type is category...?

Answer (score 0):

Your $post array's `post_type` should probably be `post`.

Comment: I agree with you. But i can insert to wp_posts any way `//        'post_type' => 'category',
        'post_type' => 'post',` and cannot to wp_term_relationships(. I checked it write now

Comment: Are you sure the category id 3 is the term id? go to the term edit page to see the id in the url. Try using the slug as the value?

Comment: Really it does`t matter id 3 or id 9. I can find my custom post in admin dashboard and added any category. I making some mistake because when  i use slug as the value its not working. I will try to find solutin i wordpress core of insert post to database. Thank for your time.